Infinite Loop in firebase cloud functions
I have two Firebase cloud functions that work together to ensure that recurring transactions are checked hourly to see if they are due.
addTransactionsScheduler

Purpose: Schedules the addTransactions function to run every hour.
Mechanism: Uses Cloud Functions’ Pub/Sub to set /addTransactionsTrigger to true every hour.

addTransactions

Trigger Activation: Listens for changes to /addTransactionsTrigger. Exits if the reference is removed.
Batch Processing Setup: Defines updateUsers to process recurring transactions in batches, starting from a given lastKey, with 10 users per batch.
Fetching and Processing Transactions:

Retrieves a batch of recurring transactions.
Checks if each transaction’s nextDate is due.
Moves completed transactions to /inactiveRecurringTransactions or updates the nextDate for active ones.
Creates new regular transactions under /transactions.


Batch Update: Writes all changes to the database in a single operation.
Pagination and Continuation: If more users remain, updates /addTransactionsTrigger to process the next batch. Logs completion and removes the trigger reference if finished.

exports.addTransactionsScheduler = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .pubsub
  .schedule("0 * * * *")
  .onRun((context) => {
    return admin.database().ref("/addTransactionsTrigger").set(true);
  });

exports.addTransactions = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .database
  .ref("/addTransactionsTrigger")
  .onWrite(async (change) => {
    if (!change.after.exists()) {
      return;
    }

    const updateUsers = async (lastKey = "0", iteration = 0, oldCounter = 0) => {
      const recurringTransactionsSnapshot = await admin.database().ref("/recurringTransactions")
        .orderByKey()
        .startAt(lastKey)
        .limitToFirst(10)
        .once("value");

      const batchUpdate = {};
      let nextKey = null;
      let counter = 0;

      recurringTransactionsSnapshot.forEach((userSnapshot) => {
        const userId = userSnapshot.key;
        if (userId !== lastKey) {
          userSnapshot.forEach((transactionSnapshot) => {
            const transactionId = transactionSnapshot.key;
            const transactionData = transactionSnapshot.val();
            if (moment(transactionData.nextDate).isSameOrBefore()) {
              if (transactionData.lastExecutionDate && moment(transactionData.lastExecutionDate).isSameOrBefore(transactionData.nextDate)) {
                batchUpdate[`/inactiveRecurringTransactions/${userId}/${transactionId}`] = transactionData;
                batchUpdate[`/recurringTransactions/${userId}/${transactionId}`] = null;
              } else {
                const newNextDate = moment(transactionData.nextDate).add(transactionData.interval.value, transactionData.interval.unit).toISOString();
                batchUpdate[`/recurringTransactions/${userId}/${transactionId}/nextDate`] = newNextDate;
              }

              batchUpdate[`/transactions/${userId}/${transactionId}`] = transactionData;
              counter++;
            }
          });

          nextKey = userId;
        }
        return false;
      });

      await admin.database().ref("/").update(batchUpdate);

      if (nextKey) {
        await change.after.ref.set({
          lastKey: nextKey,
          iteration: iteration + 1,
          records: counter + oldCounter,
        });
      } else {
        console.log(`Finished: ${iteration} iterations, ${counter + oldCounter} transactions added.`);
        await change.after.ref.remove();
      }
    };

    const data = change.after.val();

    if (data && data.lastKey) {
      return updateUsers(data.lastKey, data.iteration, data.records);
    } else {
      return updateUsers();
    }
  });

This setup ran hourly for two years without issues. A maximum of 5 instances were started and all users were iterated over once. Until a single day in May of this year. Suddenly, several thousand instances were required in Firebase, and it seemed as though the entire process ran in parallel hundreds of times. At least, the line console.log("Finished: ${iteration} iterations, ${counter + oldCounter} transactions added.") was called several hundred times for one run, which shouldn't actually happen. After a few minutes, the whole thing was over, and it hasn't happened again since.
I've been pondering this for a long time and can't understand how it could have happened.

As the issue started up without your intervention, It seems like it would require a project inspection to find the issue. It’s better to contact Google support to find the resolution.
